# Citation to original paper by Davies-Meyer on one way compression functions

Tags: hash, reference-request

I see a lot of references to the Davies-Meyer construction for one-way compression functions.

But I can't find any citation to the original paper.
Does anyone have it?

Answer (score 5):

With a little search;

First Handbook of Applied Cryptography;

> The hash function of Algorithm 9.42 and referred to as Davies-Meyer (as cited per Quisquater and Girault [1019]) has been attributed by Davies to Meyer; apparently known to Meyer and Matyas circa 1979, it was published along with Algorithm 9.41 by Matyas, Meyer, and Oseas [805].

- [805]  S.M. MATYAS, C.H. MEYER, AND J. OSEAS, “Generating strong one-way functions with cryptographic algorithm”, IBM Technical Disclosure Bulletin, 27 (1985), 5658–5659.

Also, exist in the [Merkle's Paper](https://One%20Way%20Hash%20Functions%20and%20DES) as;

- Generating strong one-way functions with cryptographic algorithm”, by S. M. Matyas. C. H. Meyer, and J. Oseas, IBM Technical Disclosure Bulletin, Vol. 27, No. 10A. March 1985 pages 5658–5659

Answer (score 4):

Despite what the name may suggest, such a publication simply does not exist. The construction was *not* proposed in joint work of Davies and Meyer.

It appears that the construction was first attributed -- without citation -- to Davies by Winternitz in "Producing a one-way hash function from DES" published at Crypto '83. However Davies himself apparently attributed the construction to Meyer in "Digital signatures, an update" (joint work with Price) published at the "5th International Conference on Computer Communication" a year later.
Alas, I cannot actually find a copy of that paper at the moment, so no idea what that attribution actually says.

It appears that the origin of the construction is unclear. The designation as Davies-Meyer stems from the two contradictory attributions mentioned above. Although crediting Davies may seem a bit silly given that he contradicts his own potential claim.